# Ring Theoretic Theorem in Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is a theorem from Hungerford's Algebra book:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring such that $R^2 = R$ (in particular, if it has an identity), then every maximal ideal $M$ in $R$ is prime.

umm...Doesn't $R^2 = R$ always hold? I am assuming that $R^2 = \{r^2 \mid r \in R\}$. What am I missing? Surely the way I have interpreted $R^2$ is incorrect.

Comment: $R^2$ is the set of all finite sums of elements like $rs$, isn't it?

Comment: Presumably Hungerford defines the notation he is using. Have you checked your assumption against what the book actually says?

Comment: @RobArthan I tried searching for through the book for a definition, but I couldn't find anything. I am working with a electronic copy, however, which makes navigating through the book a little more difficult.

Comment: He likely defines $IJ$ for ideals.  This is a special case.

Comment: Look harder and think! The proof you are looking at works with products of ideals. So look back to where ideals and sums and products of ideals are first defined. I've have never used the book before, but using the contents list I have just located the theorem you are asking about on p. 128 and the relevant definitions on p. 124 of the probably illegal copy I found on line.

Comment: IIRC for Hungerford a ring doesn't necessarily have an identity. In that case $R^2=R$ isn't necessarily true. Take for example the rng $R=2\Bbb Z$. We have $R^2=4\Bbb Z$ and $R^2\neq R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rings not necessarily with identity, the equality $R^2=R$ may not hold. The simplest case is when $R$ is a “zero ring”, that is, an abelian (additive) group with trivial multiplication $ab=0$. Another easy example is the ring (without identity) of the even integers.

Your interpretation of $R^2$ is incorrect: the set $R^2$ is the set of finite sums
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
$$
with $a_i,b_i\in R$ and is an ideal of $R$. Such a notation is the one used in virtually all textbooks on ring theory. Note that $\{r^2:r\in R\}$ is generally different from $R$ (consider the integers) and is not an ideal either.

In order to prove the statement, assume $M$ is a maximal ideal and $R^2=R$. Then, if $\bar{R}=R/M$, we have
$$
\bar{R}^2=(R^2+M)/M=R/M=\bar{R}
$$
Thus we just need to prove that if a commutative ring $R$ has no nontrivial ideals and $R^2=R$, then $R$ is a domain. Let $x\in R$. Then $xR$ is an ideal of $R$, so either $xR=\{0\}$ or $xR=R$. If $xR=\{0\}$ for every $x\in R$, then $R^2=\{0\}$, a contradiction. Therefore, $xR=R$, for at least one $x\in R$. In particular, there is $y\in R$ with $xy=x$. Prove that $y$ is the identity of $R$ and conclude.

> If $a\in R$, then $a=bx$, for some $b$, and $$ay=bxy=bx=a$$ so $y$ is the identity of $R$. Since $R$ has no nontrivial ideals, it is a field, hence it has no nonzero divisors.